# Comparing two rows in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

as part of homework i need to see if two given lectures in the table have the same teacher.

table consists of

```
lectureNr | nameOfTheLecture | hoursInWeek | professorID
```

I did the assingment, it is complicated, but I know only to do it this way:

```
select distinct ( 
       case when 
       (select professorID from vorlesungen where nameOfTheLecture like 'Logik')=
       (select professorID from vorlesungen where nameOfTheLecture like 'Erkenntnistheorie') 
       then 'yes' else 'no' end) 
from vorlesungen;
```

can anybody sugest to me a better solutiuon for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(distinct professorID) as prof_count
from vorlesungen
where nameOfTheLecture in ('Logik','Erkenntnistheorie')
```

if the count is greater `1` then they are not the same one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ANALYTIC` function `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
with data as(
select lectureNr,
       nameOfTheLecture,
       hoursInWeek,
       professorID,
       row_number() over(partition by professorID order by professorID, nameOfTheLecture) rn
from vorlesungen
where nameOfTheLecture in ('Logik','Erkenntnistheorie')
)
select * from data
where rn > 1
/
```